# Line by line input evaluation with operators and how to store the changing value until user types "."

Tags: java, methods, operators

I'm trying to make a program that evaluates a mathematic equation that's written one character or value per line at a time. The user will enter alternating numbers and operators, line by line, terminating with a ‘.’. That means I'm not trying to evaluate from a single string (and assume input will always alternate between number and operator).

I don't know how to make it so that it keeps taking input until the user types ".'

I also am not sure how to keep the value continuously changing as the user types the formula and how to store that.

Sample input:

1

+

6

-

3

.

The solution to your equation is: 4

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Evaluator {

static int add (int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

static int multiply (int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}

static int divide (int a, int b)
{
    return a / b;
}

static int subtract (int a, int b)
{
    return a - b;
}

static int modulus (int a, int b)
{
    return a % b;
}


public static void main(String [] args)
{

Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

int a,b,c;

System.out.println("Enter the equation:");

a = input.nextInt();

String c = input.next();

b = input.nextInt();


    if (c.contains("+")) {
        int result = add (a,b); 
    }
    else if (c.contains("*")) {
        int result = multiply (a,b);    
    }
    else if (c.contains("/")) {
        int result = divide (a,b);
    }
    else if (c.contains("-")) {
        int result = subtract (a,b);
    }
    else if (c.contains("%")) {
        int result = modulus (a,b);
    }
    else if (c.contains(".")) {
        break;
    }


    System.out.print("The solution to your equation is: " + result);

    }
}
```

Comment: a while() loop would be useful

Comment: Do you have you have to maintain order of operations? That would mean you would have to first get the whole expression, and then evaluate.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah No, only order of input matters, not operator precedence in this case

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz if I put a while (input.next() != ".") loop around the if statements, will that work properly? also when I try to print the result, it says I need to create the local variable result

Comment: you never define the variable result outside your if/else logic. You need to create it within scope of your entire main. Declare it right after your a,b,c variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very close, in that you use Scanner next() and nextInt() in the correct order (to match the input rules).  Here a while(true) loop is added around the pair of inputs; either a user enter a '.' and the loop breaks, or the user enters an operator followed by the next number.  The result is kept up to date by using it repeatedly in the various math operators.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int b, result;

    System.out.println("Enter the equation:");

    result = input.nextInt();

    while (true) {

        String c = input.next();
        if (c.contains(".")) {
            break;
        }

        b = input.nextInt();

        if (c.contains("+")) {
            result = add(result, b);
        } else if (c.contains("*")) {
            result = multiply(result, b);
        } else if (c.contains("/")) {
            result = divide(result, b);
        } else if (c.contains("-")) {
            result = subtract(result, b);
        } else if (c.contains("%")) {
            result = modulus(result, b);
        } 
    }
    input.close();

    System.out.print("The solution to your equation is: " + result);

}
```

Comment: this helped me so much, it works perfectly now, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple while loop you can use to get input from the user. I have a check if it's a digit or something else. You can use this skeleton to grab input from the user and exit when someone presses "."

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    int a,b,currentTotal = 0;
    String inputFromUser = "nothing";

    while(!inputFromUser.equals("."))
    {
        inputFromUser = input.nextLine(); //grab line by line
        if(inputFromUser.matches("\\d+")){
            //parse the number and set it to a value like a...
            System.out.println("You entered a number: " + inputFromUser);
        }
        else if(!inputFromUser.equals(".")){
            //check if you have value and try to apply your number to your current total
            System.out.println("You entered something other than a number: " + inputFromUser);
        }
    }
```

If the user enters a number, set a variable to that number, perhaps a

If the user enters something other than a number and not a period then check if the input is a valid operation with your provided logic and apply it like operatorMethod(a, currentTotal)